# Timer in my quiz application

Tags: android

I need help with the timer. I need a timer to activate in each question and when it is finished it should disable the radio group. The problem in this code is that when the timer finish it disable all the radio groups in all the questions.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv,mTextField;
Button btnNext;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4;
String questions[]={"First Android Phone?","Name of Android Version 4.4?","Android is which kind of software?"};
String ans[]={"Motorola Droid","Kitkat","Operating-System"};
String opt[]={"HTC-G1","HTC-One","Motorola Droid","Samsung S4","Jelly Bean","Kitkat","Froyo","Lollipop",
        "Operating-System","Antivirus","Application","Tools"};
int flag=0;
public static int marks,correct,wrong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvque);
    mTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rb3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rb4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    tv.setText(questions[flag]);
    rb1.setText(opt[0]);
    rb2.setText(opt[1]);
    rb3.setText(opt[2]);
    rb4.setText(opt[3]);
    new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            for (int i=0; i< rg.getChildCount();i++){
                rg.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
            }
            //mTextField.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            RadioButton uans=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
            if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(ans[flag]))
            {
                correct++;
            }
            else
            {
                wrong++;
            }
            flag++;
            if(flag<questions.length)
            {
                tv.setText(questions[flag]);
                rb1.setText(opt[flag*4]);
                rb2.setText(opt[(flag*4)+1]);
                rb3.setText(opt[(flag*4)+2]);
                rb4.setText(opt[(flag*4)+3]);
            }
            else
            {
                marks=correct;
                Intent in = new    Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

[UI of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHx5p.jpg)

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id = "@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Question"
    android:id="@+id/tvque" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvque"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="RadioButton"/>
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton"/>
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton"/>
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton"/>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next Question"
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv2" />
```

Comment: you are disabling all radio button in for loop. just break the loop.

Comment: The loop is for single question radio button group

Comment: @SantoshShrestha show xml and UI screenshots

Comment: As you are using same radio buttons for all questions, ones disabled, when loading another question you need to enable those. Currently you are setting the texts for radio buttons only, so you can add lines to enable the buttons after that.

Comment: Maven i have included UI screenshots and xml

Comment: Rajen thanks i enabled it for another question but my timer has not restarted

Comment: @SantoshShrestha It your timer not restarted then you need to create object of countdowntimer and afterwards you can use it anywhere to start and finish the countdowntimer.

private CountDownTimer cd;
cd = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
            Override
            public void onTick(long l) {

            }

            Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };
        cd.start();

Comment: Thanks everyone the problem is solved now for the timer and radio group

Answer (score 1):

This code now worked for me.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv,mTextField;
Button btnNext;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3,rb4;
String questions[]={"First Android Phone?","Name of Android Version 4.4?","Android is which kind of software?"};
String ans[]={"Motorola Droid","Kitkat","Operating-System"};
String opt[]={"HTC-G1","HTC-One","Motorola Droid","Samsung S4","Jelly Bean","Kitkat","Froyo","Lollipop",
        "Operating-System","Antivirus","Application","Tools"};
int flag=0;
public static int marks,correct,wrong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvque);
    mTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rb3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rb4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    tv.setText(questions[flag]);
    rb1.setText(opt[0]);
    rb2.setText(opt[1]);
    rb3.setText(opt[2]);
    rb4.setText(opt[3]);
    final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            for (int i=0; i< rg.getChildCount();i++){
                rg.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }.start();
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            RadioButton uans=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
            if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(ans[flag]))
            {
                correct++;
            }
            else
            {
                wrong++;
            }
            flag++;
            if(flag<questions.length)
            {
                tv.setText(questions[flag]);
                rb1.setText(opt[flag*4]);
                rb2.setText(opt[(flag*4)+1]);
                rb3.setText(opt[(flag*4)+2]);
                rb4.setText(opt[(flag*4)+3]);
                for (int i=0; i< rg.getChildCount();i++){
                    rg.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
                }
                Counter1.start();
            }
            else
            {
                marks=correct;
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private CountDownTimer timer;
onCrate()....
  ....

  timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {....};
  timer.start();
  ....

  onClick(){....
    rb4.setText(opt[(flag * 4) + 3]);
    timer.start();
  };
```